# Asterisk 911 dialing rule

Tags: asterisk

Our company is looking to replace our outdated PBX with VoIP. One function we really like about our current PBX is that it alerts the secretary when a line dials 911 and it shows the extension where the 911 call was placed. The secretary is then responsible for emailing HR, Facilities, and the on-campus nurse to help in aiding the situation (if needed).

How would I set up a rule in asterisk to do the above automatically?

The 911 call will get the priority as seen [here](http://www.hurdman.net/mirror/voip-info/wiki/view/Asterisk+tips+911.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to determine how to notify the secretary using an AGI command and a growl implementation. Here are the links that helped me:

http://tech.iprock.com/?p=3675 (DHCP addresses + sshing)

https://web.archive.org/web/20150306223203/http://www.freepbx.org/support/documentation/howtos/how-to-set-up-notification-caller-id-popup-on-mac-os-x-linux-and-other- (Static IP + growl native)